Average order of events with weighted probabilities
I have this question that seems easy but I can't find a way to solve it. I'm trying to mod a game and I faced this question.
Let's say I have some events $e_1, e_2...$ with each a volume (or number of iterations) $v_1, v_2...$ and a probability $p_1, p_2...$
In total there are $V = \sum v_i$ events happening (so all of them), and we are looking into the order in which they happen.
For the first event, each event $e_i$ has a probability $\frac{v_i * p_i}{\sum_k v_k*p_k}$ to happen, then if $e_1$ happened first for instance, then the next probability is $P(e_{i \not = 1)} = \frac{v_i * p_i}{\sum_k v_k*p_k - p_1}$ and $p(e_1) = \frac{(v_1-1) * p_1}{\sum_k v_k*p_k - p_1}$
It's like drawing balls without replacement, with each type of ball having a weighted probability of being picked. You can think of it as different objects and bigger objects have a higher chance of being picked than smaller ones.
So my question is, when all events happened, what's the average order for each event ?
Thank you for any insight on this question.

I do not see the weights.  It looks to me as if you have various coloured balls ($v_i$ balls of colour $e_i$) and you put all the $\sum v_k$ balls in a random order.  Nor am I sure what you might then call an average order for each event/colour: in the first $n$ balls, the expectation might be to have seen $\frac{v_i}{\sum v_k}n$ balls of colour $e_i$ but that is not an order.

Hey, thanks for your comment. Yes this is the easy question, if all the $p_i$ are equal. Then all the average order for each colour are the same, because all the colours of balls have the same likeliness to be picked (if they are in equal number).
But here in my case we have different size, so bigger objects are more likely to be picked and that will affect the order. For the first object picked for example, the most likely to be picked is the one with the highest $v_i * p_i$, which can be the highest $v_i$, but it can also be a more scarce object with a very high $p_i$.

You can see it as a stochastic process. I´m going to change a little bit your problem in order to speak easily. If you have $m$ different types of balls and you call them $1,2,3,...,m$ and for the ball of type $k$ you have $n_{k}$ balls, and the probability of pick one (when you have one ball of each type) is $p_{k}$ and the time is represented by the variable $n$ (when you pick one ball then $n$ increases in 1) then you can define de random varibale $Y_{n}$ where the event $\lbrace Y_{n}=k \rbrace$ represent "to pick a ball of type $k$ at the time $n$". Now you can see that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{\lbrace Y_{i}=k \rbrace}$ (where $\mathbb{I}_{A}(x)$ is equal to $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ elswhere) counts the numbers of balls of type $k$ that you´ve picked at the time $n$, therefore $N_{n+1}(k):=n_{k}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{\lbrace Y_{i}=k \rbrace}$ is the number of balls of type $k$ that remains after $n$ picks. You can see that $P_{n+1}(k):=\frac{N_{n+1}(k)p_{k}}{\sum_{i=1}^{m}N_{n+1}(i)p_{i}}$ represent the probability of the event $\lbrace Y_{n+1}=k \rbrace$. Notice that $P_{n}(k)$ is a random variable, not a probability. Now if you define $\overrightarrow{Y}=(Y_{1},...Y_{n_{max}})$ where $n_{max}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}$, then you have to compute $E(\overrightarrow{Y})$.
Well, this is not easy to cumpute, but you can use Montecarlo´s simulation to see what happen. Notice that $E(Y_{1})$ is easy to compute, then this will be the first coordinate of $E(\overrightarrow{Y})$. The last value will approach to the type of ball with less probability $p_{k}$ and all coordinate will change "smoothly" to this value.
I expect that this answer can help you
